# Loading one line from Three Phase Power Delta Configuration

Tags: power, three-phase, single-phase, delta

I have been trying to determine whether or not I can run one line from 3-phase power into a power conditioner that requires single-phase input.

The current draw on this line would be around 10 A. Would this cause issues with current unbalance?

Comment: If it's delta, where are you getting the neutral from?

Answer (score -1):

Imbalance requires some knowledge of all loads. Although 10A may not seem like much on power up surge load imbalance of motors and SMPS inverters is often overlooked which can cause over voltage on startup of the unused or light loaded phases to linear power supplies.